# what's wrong with this QuickSort, I refer it from book

Tags: c++, quicksort

I wrote a program, contain QuickSort to sort some datas include in vector

I reference to .--Mark Allen Weiss, but when I excute it under VS2015 && G++ 4.8, to program failed.

only thing I'm sure is other part of my program is right.
some data generate, and read them to vector
(compare the property between QuickSort and MergeSort, while MergeSort went well when text)

```
void QuickSort(vector<int> &a) {
    QuickSort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
}

int median3(vector<int> &a, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) >> 1;
    if (a[mid] < a[left])
        swap(a[left], a[mid]);
    if (a[right] < a[left])
        swap(a[left], a[right]);
    if (a[right] < a[mid])
        swap(a[mid], a[right]);
    swap(a[mid], a[right - 1]);
    return a[right - 1];
}
void QuickSort(vector<int> &a, int left, int right) {
    //if (left + 10 <= right) {
        int pivot = median3(a, left, right);

        // begin partitioning
        int i = left, j = right -1;
        for ( ; ; ) {
            while (a[++i] < pivot){ }
            while (pivot  < a[--j]){ }
            if (i < j)
                swap(a[i], a[j]);
            else break;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[right - 1]);   // restore pivot

        QuickSort(a, left, i - 1);  // store small element
        QuickSort(a, i + 1, right); // store large element
    // }
    // else
    //     InsertionSort(a, left, right);
}
```

compile success in VS && G++, while VS givin warning:
  function may cause stack over flow in runtime

I'm puzzling it for two days, so sad . . .

Comment: `void QuickSort(vector<int> &a) {
    QuickSort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
}`  ??

Comment: When you used a debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables at the statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `right` is larger than `left` before you pass them into `QuickSort(a, left, right)`. Otherwise, the position may be out of range when you try to access `a[]`.

Also, you don't need to swap your pivot to the end in `median3` and then "restore" it in `QuickSort`. Just let your `i` and `j` indices start from two ends of the vector and then swap the number less than the pivot with the number larger than pivot.

```
void QuickSort(vector<int> &a, int left, int right) {

    int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];

    // begin partitioning
    int i = left, j = right;
    for ( ; ;) {
        while (a[i] < pivot){ ++i; }
        while (pivot < a[j]){ --j; }
        if (i < j){
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
        else break;
    }

    if (left < i-1) QuickSort(a, left, i - 1);  // store small element
    if (i+1 < right) QuickSort(a, i + 1, right); // store large element
}
```